# clicking data in datagridview then passing the data to popup window

Tags: c#, datagridview

i just want to ask, how will i code when i want to pass a data into a popup window by clicking a `Column` in `DataGridView`. please help!

```
try
{
    Lessee_Message frm = new Lessee_Message(
        dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells["ID"].Value.ToString())); 
    frm .ShowDialog();
}
catch(Exception a) { }
```

what is wrong with this code?

Comment: this code Lessee_Message frm = new Lessee_Message(
        dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells["ID"].Value.ToString())); has always redline and an error that is "Lessee_Message does not take more than 1 argument"

Comment: First: you have one `)` more than you need `new Lessee_Message(dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells["ID"].Value.ToString());`  What constructors you have in `Lessee_Message` class?

Answer (score 0):

You must create an overloaded constructor in Lessee_Message form to pass a string as parameter.

Lessee_Message should have something like this:

```
public partial class Lessee_Message : Form
{    
//This is only for further use. only to pass a parameter, the private field is not required.
private string _id="";
 public Lessee_Message (string id)
 {
_id=id;
 InitializeComponent ();
 }

}
```